# What is the technical name of this type of chart?

Tags: terminology

I see this type of chart in many different video games that gives a breakdown of performance in various categories. Is there a technical name for this type of chart?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a Radar Chart, also known as a Web Chart or Spider Chart. They are often used for comparing multiple outcome variables.

The number of points the chart has depends on the numbers of variables. That one (which is from League of Legends I believe) has three variables, while the one commonly used in Pokémon has six (one point for each of the stats).

[The Wikipedia Article for Radar Charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart)

And here are some examples of Radar Charts in gaming:

[image: Pokémon Stat Radar Chart from Sword and Shield]

The above is the Pokémon Effort Value Radar Chart from Pokémon Sword and Shield.

[image: Pokémon Contest Radar Chart from Emerald]

The above is the Pokémon Contest Stat Radar Chart from Pokémon Emerald.

[image: League Radar Charts]

The above are the Gameplay Efficiency Radar Charts from League of Legends. The left is your account wide Playstyle Radar Chart, and the right is a character specific one comparing your stats with all players on the same character.

Comment: Additional info: The Pokémon one you refer to displays EVs and IVs for the stats. Some Pokémon generations use another radar chart to display the 5 Pokémon Contest stats, with one iteration I know of (Gen3 remakes) bending the chart's outline into a star-like shape.

Comment: @EgorHans Oh yeah, I forgot about those lol. I think I am gonna update my post with some examples of the ones from Pokémon.